# Pandas bar plot of means aggregates all items

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to display the average of some items in a bar plot and I am using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


items = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'b':[3,4,5,6,7],
    'c':[5,6,7,8,9]
})

df_mean = df.mean().to_frame().T

print(df_mean)

df_mean.plot.bar()
plt.legend(items)
plt.show()
```

It works, but all the bars are aggregated under a single x value of 0. Can I break this?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the transposition (i.e., do `df_mean =  df.mean().to_frame()`), you get this:

[image]

You can also use something like `plt.legend(['Value'])` to make a more sensible legend.